Error dissnake pyanywhere
Написал бота на disnake и столкнулся с проблемой хостинга:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/popa228337123/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1025, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1064, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1049, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 960, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 500, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 535, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('162.159.128.233', 443)
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/popa228337123/dsb/bot.py", line 160, in <module>
    bot.run('*токен*')
  File "/home/popa228337123/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/disnake/client.py", line 1126, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/home/popa228337123/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/disnake/client.py", line 1105, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/popa228337123/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/disnake/client.py", line 1066, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/home/popa228337123/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/interaction_bot_base.py", line 224, in login
    await super().login(token)
  File "/home/popa228337123/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/common_bot_base.py", line 131, in login
    await super().login(token=token)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/popa228337123/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/disnake/client.py", line 865, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token.strip())
  File "/home/popa228337123/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/disnake/http.py", line 462, in static_login
    data: user.User = await self.request(Route("GET", "/users/@me"))
  File "/home/popa228337123/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/disnake/http.py", line 338, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as response:
  File "/home/popa228337123/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1197, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/popa228337123/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 581, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/home/popa228337123/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 544, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/popa228337123/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 944, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/popa228337123/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1257, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/home/popa228337123/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1226, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/home/popa228337123/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1033, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('162.159.128.233', 443)]

Сам код:
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands, tasks
import os
import random
import json
import datetime
from loguru import logger
import asyncio
# Логи
logger.add("bot.log", rotation="80 MB")

intents = disnake.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
intents.messages = True
intents.guilds = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

user_data_file = 'user_data.json'

# Функция загрузки данных пользователей из файла
def load_user_data():
    try:
        with open(user_data_file, 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            # Преобразование строк обратно в datetime объекты
            for user_id, user_data in data.items():
                if 'last_bonus' in user_data and user_data['last_bonus'] is not None:
                    user_data['last_bonus'] = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(
                        user_data['last_bonus']
                    )
            logger.info("Данные пользователей успешно загружены") # Логи
            return data
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logger.warning(
            "Файл с данными пользователей не найден. Будет создан новый файл." # Лог ошибки
        )
        return {}

# Функция сохранения данных пользователей в файл
def save_user_data(data):
    with open(user_data_file, 'w') as f:
        # Преобразование datetime объектов в строки перед записью в JSON
        for user_id, user_data in data.items():
            if 'last_bonus' in user_data and isinstance(
                user_data['last_bonus'], datetime.datetime
            ):
                user_data['last_bonus'] = user_data['last_bonus'].isoformat()
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
    logger.info("Данные пользователей сохранены") # Логи

user_data = load_user_data()

# Функция выдачи бонуса пользователю
def give_bonus(user_id):
    user_id = str(user_id)
    if user_id not in user_data:
        user_data[user_id] = {'balance': 0, 'last_bonus': None}
    if user_data[user_id]['last_bonus'] is None or (
            datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(user_data[user_id]['last_bonus'].isoformat())
    ).total_seconds() >= 86400:
        bonus_amount = random.randint(-7, 20)
        user_data[user_id]['balance'] += bonus_amount
        user_data[user_id]['last_bonus'] = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
        save_user_data(user_data)
        return True
    return False

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    logger.info(f'Бот {bot.user} подключен к Discord!') # Логи

last_pinged_user = None

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global last_pinged_user

    if bot.user.mentioned_in(message):
        if not reset_ping.is_running():
            reset_ping.start()

        if message.author.id == last_pinged_user:
            await message.channel.send("Да чё тебе от меня надо? /info напиши уже и не пингуй меня, бездарь")
        else:
            phrases = ["Чо нада?", "Чо хотел?"]
            random_phrase = random.choice(phrases)
            await message.channel.send(random_phrase)

        last_pinged_user = message.author.id

    await bot.process_commands(message)

@tasks.loop(seconds=300)
async def reset_ping():
    global last_pinged_user
    last_pinged_user = None
    logger.info('Память о пингах сброшена')

@bot.slash_command(name='info', description='Узнать команды бота')
async def infa(interaction: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction):
    sms = f"**Список команд:**\n\n!razmer - Узнать размер линейки\n!lin - Вырастить/уменьшить линейку\n!top - Топ линеек\n/ping - Узнать пинг бота"
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=disnake.Embed(description = sms, color = disnake.Color.orange()))

@bot.slash_command(name="sync", description="Синхронизирует Slash-команды")
@commands.is_owner()
async def sync(interaction: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction):
    try:
        await bot._sync_application_commands()
        await interaction.response.send_message("✅ Slash-команды успешно синхронизированы!", ephemeral=True)
    except disnake.HTTPException as e:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"❌ Ошибка при синхронизации команд: {e}", ephemeral=True)

@bot.command(name="ping", description="Показывает пинг бота")
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(embed=disnake.Embed(description = f" Понг! Задержка: {round(bot.latency * 1000)} мс", color = disnake.Color.orange()))


@bot.command(name='razmer')
async def balance(ctx):
    user_id = str(ctx.author.id)
    if user_id not in user_data:
        user_data[user_id] = {'balance': 0, 'last_bonus': None}
        save_user_data(user_data)
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, твоя линейка: {user_data[user_id]['balance']} см.")

@bot.command(name='lin')
async def bonus(ctx):
    user_id = str(ctx.author.id)
    if give_bonus(user_id):
        sms = f"{ctx.author.mention}\nТы получил бонусные см"
        await ctx.send(embed=disnake.Embed(description = sms, color = disnake.Color.orange()))
    else:
        sms = f"{ctx.author.mention}\nКД в 24 часа ещё не прошло, жди дальше..."
        await ctx.send(embed=disnake.Embed(description = sms, color = disnake.Color.orange()))

@bot.command(name='top')
async def top(ctx):
    top_users = sorted(user_data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['balance'], reverse=True)[:10]

    top_list = " **Топ линеек:**\n\n"
    for i, (user_id, data) in enumerate(top_users):
        user = await bot.fetch_user(int(user_id))  # Получение объекта пользователя по ID
        top_list += f"{i+1}. {user.name} - {data['balance']} см\n"

    await ctx.send(embed=disnake.Embed(description = top_list, color = disnake.Color.orange()))

@bot.slash_command(name="top", description= "Узнать топ линеек")
async def topchik(ctx):
    top_users = sorted(user_data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['balance'], reverse=True)[:10]

    top_list = " **Топ линеек:**\n\n"
    for i, (user_id, data) in enumerate(top_users):
        user = await bot.fetch_user(int(user_id))  # Получение объекта пользователя по ID
        top_list += f"{i+1}. {user.name} - {data['balance']} см\n"

    await ctx.send(embed=disnake.Embed(description = top_list, color = disnake.Color.orange()))

bot.run('*токен*')

Узнал только то, что нужно использовать прокси, но как интегрировать его в этот код я понятия не имею, помогите!

Попробуйте при создании бота добавить параметр proxy: bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents, proxy="proxy.server:3128"), также попробуйте с http и https: http://proxy.server:3128, https://proxy.server:3128

Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1584970/1365
